# researching greater detail about word difficulty

Tags: word-usage

I noticed that dictionary.com has a word difficulty index which is called "proprietary."

Questions:
Is there an open source list of English words that assigns a difficulty index value to each word?

Are there other indices available?

Is there any position paper (or better) publication that explains how they derive this index for each word?

Comment: I'm also looking for something like a difficulty index. According to this [blog post](http://blog.dictionary.com/welcome-to-our-new-redesign/), the index is based both on the complexity and frequency of use.

Comment: Maybe in k-12 instructional materials there exist lists like: vocabulary words for Grade 1, for Grade 2, and so on.  Somehow publishers of books for children have a method of assigning an appropriate reading grade-level to them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not about usage per se. It's about research books/sites.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a number of legitimate ways of scoring a word that are comparable to this unexplained 'difficulty'. There could be:

- frequency - the number of occurrences of a word for a given corpus
- complexity/readability - number of syllables/sounds/characters
- questions - the number of times a question (or dictionary search) is performed on the word (for a given on-line dictionary/web app)

Surely there are other possible ones. There are a number of online resources that [list English words by frequency](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+word+frequency+ranking), and some online dictionaries, too ([Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) doesn't give a list but allows comparison by frequency). Readability is easily calculated per word (once you choose your metric). Number of searches on a word is very app-specific and also very volatile, depending very much on if a particular uncommon word is used by someone in the news. I can't find any where on line about dictionary.com's method of calculation

There is still the matter of judging what exactly difficulty should be among a combination of these and any others. I think frequency is what most people really are thinking of when 'difficulty' is being used. 'periodically' is way more 'complex' than 'nonce' but is also way more frequent.